# Vector in class (does not have a class type)

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have some trouble with vector in class.

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class sth {
    vector<int> tab();
    public:
        void add(int i);
};

void sth::add(int i){
    tab.push_back(i);
}

int main() {
    sth a;
    a.add(10);
    return 0;
}
```

That simple code causes `11 5 [Error] '((sth*)this)->sth::tab' does not have class type`
Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: `vector<int> tab();` This is a function declararation!! You wanted `vector<int> tab;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is actually a function declaration:

```
vector<int> tab();
```

If you want to declare an `std::vector`, it should be:

```
vector<int> tab;
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, would you agree it fully explains the problem, and feasible fixes?

Answer (score 1):

> That simple code causes
>   `11 5 [Error] '((sth*)this)->sth::tab' does not have class type`
>   Any ideas what is going on?

What you have used is a *class member function* declaration:

```
vector<int> tab();
```

As I can read from your `add()` method implementation, you wanted to declare (and initialize?) a *class member **variable***. To achieve this, the declaration syntax looks like this:

```
vector<int> tab;
```

---

To initialize your class member variables (even using their default constructors), you have to use the constructor methods member initialization list for the definition

```
sth::sth() : tab() {}
```

For the current c++ standard, you can also use a direct initialization with one of the following forms

```
vector<int> tab{};
vector<int> tab{1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> tab = vector<int>();
```

Comment: The last part's not entirely accurate. You *can* initialize data members where they're defined using C++11 non-static data member initializers. In this case, the OP could use `vector<int> tab{};` (or `vector<int> tab = vector<int>();`) but it's unnecessary.